# Optimize escape JSON in PostgreSQL 9.0

Tags: json, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm currently using this JSON escaping function in PostgreSQL as a stand in for future native JSON support.  While it works, it's also limiting our systems performance.  How can I go about optimizing it?  Maybe some kind of lookup array?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION escape_json(i_text TEXT) 
RETURNS TEXT AS
$body$                                                  
DECLARE
  idx INTEGER;
  text_len INTEGER;   
  cur_char_unicode INTEGER;
  rtn_value TEXT := i_text;
BEGIN
  -- $Rev: $ --
  text_len = LENGTH(rtn_value);
  idx = 1; 

  WHILE (idx <= text_len) LOOP
    cur_char_unicode = ASCII(SUBSTR(rtn_value, idx, 1));

    IF cur_char_unicode > 255 THEN
      rtn_value = OVERLAY(rtn_value PLACING (E'\\u' || LPAD(UPPER(TO_HEX(cur_char_unicode)),4,'0')) FROM idx FOR 1);
      idx = idx + 5;
      text_len = text_len + 5;
    ELSE
      /* is the current character one of the following: " \ / bs ff nl cr tab */
      IF cur_char_unicode IN (34, 92, 47, 8, 12, 10, 13, 9) THEN
        rtn_value = OVERLAY(rtn_value PLACING (E'\\' || (CASE cur_char_unicode
                                                         WHEN 34 THEN '"'
                                                         WHEN 92 THEN E'\\'
                                                         WHEN 47 THEN '/'
                                                         WHEN  8 THEN 'b'
                                                         WHEN 12 THEN 'f'
                                                         WHEN 10 THEN 'n'
                                                         WHEN 13 THEN 'r'
                                                         WHEN  9 THEN 't'
                                                          END)
                                        )
                                FROM idx FOR 1);

        idx = idx + 1;
        text_len = text_len + 1;
      END IF;
    END IF;

    idx = idx + 1;
  END LOOP;                   

  RETURN rtn_value;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All my approaches boil down to "do it some other way":

- Write it in some other language, e.g. use pl/perl, pl/python, pl/ruby
- Write a wrapper round some external JSON library written in C
- Do the JSON escaping in the client rather than in the query (assuming your client has some good JSON escaping support)

In my experience pl/pgsql isn't fast at this sort of thing- its strength is in its integral support for exchanging data with the database, not as a general-purpose programming language.

Example:

```
create or replace function escape_json_perl(text) returns text 
  strict immutable
  language plperlu as $$
    use JSON;
    return JSON->new->allow_nonref->encode($_[0]);
  $$;
```

A quick test suggests this is on the order of 15x faster than the plpgsql function (although it returns quotes around the value which you probably want to strip off)

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I'll just encode my heavy stored procs in python until they release 9.1

Comment: @gradbot: I don't think there is going to be built-in JSON support in 9.1.

Comment: @Peter looks like your right.  I did a search of 9.1 alpha source and the only reference to JSON I find is this. `"EXPLAIN" enhancements. The output is now available in JSON, XML or YAML format`

Answer (score 7):

*Confession: I am the Google Summer of Code 2010 student who was going to try to bring JSON support to PostgreSQL 9.1.  Although my code was fairly feature-complete , it wasn't completely ready for upstream, and the PostgreSQL development community was looking at some alternative implementations.  However, with spring break coming up, I'm hoping to finish my rewrite and give it a final push this week.*

In the mean time, you can download and install the [work-in-progress JSON data type module](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb?p=json-datatype.git;a=summary), which should work on PostgreSQL 8.4.0 and up.  It is a PGXS module, so you can compile and install it without having to compile all of PostgreSQL.  However, you will need the PostgreSQL server development headers.

Installation goes something like this:

```
git clone git://git.postgresql.org/git/json-datatype.git
cd json-datatype/
USE_PGXS=1 make
sudo USE_PGXS=1 make install
psql -f json.sql <DBNAME1> # requires database superuser privileges
```

Although the build and install only needs to be done once, `json.sql` needs to be run on every database you plan to use the JSON data type on.

With that installed, you can now run:

```
=> SELECT to_json(E'"quotes and \n newlines"\n'::TEXT);
            to_json             
--------------------------------
 "\"quotes and \n newlines\"\n"
(1 row)
```

Note that this does not escape non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a PostgreSQL function implemented in C here : http://code.google.com/p/pg-to-json-serializer/

I have not compared it with your PLSQL method but it should be faster than any interpreted language.

Another one : http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/json-functions-for-postgresql