# PostgreSQL how to query json data based upon json attribs criteria

Tags: json, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL i want to store JSON data into table column.
Later i want to retrieve data records criteria based upon JSON attributes.
I know sort of this support available in MS SQL Server but i don't know that is it available in PostgreSQL or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [json-datatype](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=json-datatype.git;a=tree) project from Google Summer of Code 2010 (especially check json.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995945/optimize-escape-json-in-postgresql-9-0/5448248#5448248).

Comment: it is not default support thats why we moved to default xml support of pgsql

Answer (score 2):

How about using [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html) and formatting it to JSON with [these formatting functions](https://gist.github.com/2318757)?